# Installing mod_python on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, mod-python

I'd rather not use Macports. Simply cause Macport replaces (installs another Apache in /opt/local/bin) the default installation of Apache. And that would mean having ports install/replace PHP too. I'd rather use the default installation included in Snow Leopard.

Been searching the net, and all I get is old instructions using Darwin Ports (older version of Macports) or instruction for Leopard (which hasn't panned out for me).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

PS: By the way mod_python for 1.6 or 3.1 is fine.

Comment: I didn't like the idea of macports installing its own copy of apps that where distributed with the os either.  But I gave it a try and I've been using it for a few years now.  It's very solid, I think you will be happy with the results if you get familiar with macports.

Comment: Doing that now. Ah well. It does make it very easy.

Comment: Hey Palo.. thanks. I usually ignored Macport simply out of ignorance. Now installing my whole development system via it.  Sure beats the hell out of compiling it all myself, blindly. ;) I'm gonna mark this questioned as answered and point to this thread. Thanks again.

Comment: The mod_python package doesn't support Python 3.X and likely never will. The mod_python package also not likely to work with Apache 2.3 (2.4) either unless work done in porting it. Its days are numbered.

Comment: Yeah. I have since found that out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seems that the mod_python development has somewhat stalled. I've read comments that, for wsgi-capable applications like Trac or Django, [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) is sufficient. Mod_wsgi compiles without problems on Snow Leopard (of course you need the Developer tools installed).

Of course, Macports or Fink is always an alternative. However, as opposed to Leopard where the supplied Apache and Python binaries were rather old, the Snow Leopard ones are current and 64-bit as well. Another advantage of using the Apple supplied binaries is that they get automatic security updates with the usual Apple Software Update. Last but not least you have better OS integration with using the standard supplied Apache.

Answer (score 0):

[fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) is the alternative distribution to [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).  Given you're installing a module, it would most likely update your Apache instance as well.

Sounds like you'll probably need to build Apache (to get the header files/libraries you need to link to) and mod_python.

Comment: Yeah. I assumed that. Was hoping for an easier install. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to avoid macports, I recommend checking out the mod_python trunk. I was actually able to build it with apache2 and Python 2.5 successfully without having to tweak the source of any of all the previously reported issues

svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/quetzalcoatl/mod_python/trunk mod_python-trunk

Macports is great if you are starting with a clean slate. But often you are just migrating systems (migrations assistant never gets the mod_python over) or even just upgrading the OS (had to rebuild mod_python for snow leopard)

:)

Comment: FYI. You can still have issues with mod_python trunk if not using standard Python supplied by Apple but an alternate distribution. This will be evident by mod_python finding wrong Python installation at runtime or completely failing at startup with undefined symbols.

Comment: I didn't use Apple's shipped Python. Our source code is old and is Python 2.5 while Apple now ships 2.6. I had to finagle with the /Library folders and explicitly specify which python bin file to use at build time